# how to synchronize between local DB (SQLite) and Parse using objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, synchronization

I want to sync data with local database while internet is not available and whenever internet is available i want to parse the data to the local server.I m using SQLite database and I m using json format to parse the data.

Can anyone suggest me how can i do this one?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: i think you mean to say that, if internet is available then data comes from server and if not then it comes from local database....right????

Comment: No, i want to do that if net is not available then data will stored in my db that i've done and when net is avaible than data will upload on the server.

Comment: Like in my database, i've firstname last name and address fields.now if net is not available than i'll store that data on my db.

Comment: once net is available thn this data will upload on my local server

Comment: ok...then what i think is ,,you should fetch every data from local db whenever net is available and delete all data from server and replace fetched data with it....

Comment: hey sweeta... as fas as i understand you want to store data locally and when net connection available you want to sync with parse. is this you want?

Comment: Yeas..Dalvik i want exactly that

Comment: have you read about PARSE LOCAL DATASTORE

Comment: you can save objects offline there is no need of sqlite.

Comment: lets discuss the problm here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71170/ios-magicians

Answer (score 0):

i would use CoreData instead of directly SQLite. Then you can create an entity which represents the attributes/properties you want to save and an additional BOOL transmitted. When you're offline, you set the BOOL to NO.

After getting notified that internet is available, for example from Reachability Framework from Apple, you could easily fetch the Objects with transmitted=NO from CoreData and send the data to the server.